Get Content Hub image referenced in Sitecore field with Glass mapper
In the Sitecore image field, we refer to the image from Content Hub. Previously, in our .cshtml file, we had the glass mapper code to render the image from the field, referenced from the Sitecore media library.
@RenderImage(Model.DataItemModel, x => x.Image, new { @class = "with-media__img with-media__img--right" }, isEditable: true)

Now, after referencing the image in the field from Content Hub, the image is not rendering and I had to use @Html.Sitecore().Field("Image") then only it was working.
So, do we have any Glass Mapper code so we don't have to change it much?
